# When installing rigid dryer vent and connecting pieces

Tags: vent, dryer, ducts

When installing rigid dryer vent and connecting pieces together do I use foil tape or those circle things you put on outside with a screw to tighten?  Also is it a good idea to use duct connectors between each piece of pipe?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Each piece of duct should fit into each other piece, in such a way that the piece closest to the dryer should fit into the piece further from the dryer.  This way,  there's no ridges for lint to get caught on.  You'll use a crimping tool, to crimp the end of ducts so that they fit into the next section.

[image: duct crimper]

You can then seal the seam with foil faced tape, that is listed for the use. This will prevent leaks, and hold the duct sections together.

It's not recommend to use screws for attaching sections of duct, as they could provide places for lint to get snagged.

You'll also want to support and secure the duct, so that it's held firmly in place. This will reduce the stresses on the joints.